# Search columns affected after csv download in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

We currently have an issue in which, after downloading a CSV file, when reloading the page, we get an error. While diving in, I found out that it's because the returned data is missing the three columns we removed from the CSV file. We needed the `deleted_at` column for our search fields. I kind of wonder why this is happening.

This is the code on our controller's index:

```
def index
    @q        = Client.with_deleted.search(session[:clients_q])

    #the deleted_at_present is what causes the error, because the deleted_at becomes missing after the csv download

    if @q.deleted_at_present.blank?
      @q.deleted_at_present = false
    end

    @page     =params[:page]
    @clients = @q.result(distinct: true).page(@page)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @q.result(distinct: true).to_csv, :filename =>  NKF.nkf('-s',"#{Client.model_name.human.titleize}_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")}.csv")  }
    end
  end
```

This is the code for creating the csv in the model rb:

```
  def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate(force_quotes: true) do |csv|
      csv << csv_column_names_i18n
      all.each do |client|
        csv << client.csv_column_values
      end
    end
  end

 def self.csv_column_names

    csv_column_names = self.column_names

    csv_column_names.delete('updated_at')
    csv_column_names.delete('created_at')
    csv_column_names.delete('deleted_at')
    return csv_column_names
  end

  def self.csv_column_names_i18n
    require 'nkf'
    require 'kconv'

    csv_column_names = self.csv_column_names

    return_column_names = []

    csv_column_names.each do |csv_column_name|
      return_column_names << NKF.nkf('-s',self.human_attribute_name(csv_column_name.to_sym))
    end

    return return_column_names
  end

  def csv_column_values
    require 'nkf'
    require 'kconv'

    return_column_values = []

    self.attributes.except('updated_at','created_at','deleted_at').each do |key, value|
      if key == 'id' || value.nil?
        return_column_values << value
      else
       return_column_values << NKF.nkf('-s',"#{value}")
      end
    end

    return return_column_values

  end
```

This is the result before CSV download:
[image]

This is the result after the CSV download:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue here looks like it's in your `self.csv_column_names` method. You're grabbing a *reference* to `self.column_names`, so when you call `delete` on it, you're actually deleting from `self.column_names`. Because it's changing it on a class method, it persists across requests.

Try changing the first line of the method to:

```
csv_column_names = self.column_names.dup
```

Note the `.dup`. Another way you could go about it is to do:

```
def self.csv_column_names
  column_names - %w[updated_at created_at deleted_at]
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking that it was a reference issue, but can't find out which of the following is the issue. I never thought it would be the column names. Big thanks for your help. There's still a time limit on the bounty, I'll reward it to you as soon as it's up.